# Document not ready for insert after method using a loop with jquery

Tags: jquery, insert, load, loops, document

Is there a way to use a loop to insert separate DIV elements behind each other?

Right now I use a loop to do just that, but it doesn't remember the DIV inserted
before with the load method. The result is that I only see the last one.

The code is meant to show all messages, after it reads the cookie with the db-id when you
first arrive at the page.

summary:

the `addmessage()` function receives the xml-object and starts looping through it. Each separate message calls the `newnote()` function, which loads a DIV element and does stuff in its callback function like setting the `db-id`. After that it returns to the `addmessage` function.

Answer (score 1):

What method are you using to insert the DIVs? If you just want them all added to the end of whatever container you're using, you could just using `append`. If you need them in a particular location, I'd use `before` or `after`

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="itemOne"></div>
    <div id="itemTwo"></div>
    <div id="itemThree"></div>
</div>
```

If you needed to insert something after itemTwo:

```
$('#itemTwo').after("<div>New node</div>");
```

If you're doing this in a loop and need to keep adding them sequentially after itemTwo (for example), then you could try either storing a reference to the last-inserted element, and then use the `after` function on that, or by inserting it before the following item, itemThree.

Comment: do you mean, storing it in a reference outside these functions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is finding the last DIV, you can search for the [last](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/last) DIV and just place it [after](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/after#content) that.

Comment: the problem is that I already am using the after method in the callback off the load method in the newnote()function
The load method loads one note from a seperate file

The problem is that I have too loop this function, but I loose any reference too the last inserted note if I keep calling the newnote()
function from the main function addmessage
I had the problem before with loading one note, but that was solved by doing stuff in the callback off the loadmethod. Now I have to create more then one note in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
also with help from above, with the suggestion off having a reference

If I try to count the number off newly added elements with the selector like this

```
index = $("div.paneltbnote").size();
```

the result is always 0

BUT, if you explicitly give the indexnumber to the newnote() function, it works like it is supposed too. I just added a counter to the loop and used that, as an extra argument for the function

The selector cannot count newly added elements within the function itself.
At least, that is my understanding sofar.